# Extract df from a summary object in R

Tags: r, dataframe, statistics, regression, lm

I was wondering in my R code below, how I can extract `df` values from the `ems$emmeans` object?

```
library(lme4)
library(emmeans)
dat <- read.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hkil/m/master/z.csv')
dat$year <- as.factor(dat$year)

m1 <- lmer(y~year*group + (1|stid), data = dat)

ems <- emmeans(m1, pairwise ~ group*year, infer = c(T, T))

# How to extract 'df' values from ems$emmeans?
```

Comment: still I am getting Inf, I get a `Note` that `D.f. calculations have been disabled because the number of observations exceeds 3000.
To enable adjustments, add the argument 'pbkrtest.limit = 3435' (or larger)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is `as.data.frame` method for 'emmGrid'

```
methods(class = 'emmGrid')
#[1] [             +             as.data.frame as.glht       as.list       CLD           coef          confint      
#[9] contrast      pairs         plot          predict       print         rbind         show          str          
#[17] summary       test          update        vcov
```

So, we can convert the output of 'emmeans' to `data.frame` and extract the 'df' with `$` or `[[`

```
as.data.frame(ems$emmeans)$df
```

---

There is a `Note` which suggest that `D.f. calculations are disable because the observations exceed 3000 and to enable, add 'pbkrtest.limit = 3435'

```
ems <- emmeans(m1, pairwise ~ group*year, infer = c(T, T), pbkrtest.limit = 3435)
as.data.frame(ems$emmeans)$df
#[1] 3090.821 2994.815 3328.634 3164.587 3380.889 3371.980
```

Comment: @rnorouzian you can create a function `f1 <- function(model, data) if(nrow(data) > 3000 emmeans(model, ...., pbkr.test.limit = 3435) else ...` or there is also an option to `update` the emmGrid

Comment: @rnorouzian no, I am not aware

Comment: Sure, appreciate it, Thanks!